# Iterate over every nth element in string in loop - python

Tags: python, string, loops, iteration

**How can iterate over every second element in string ?**

One way  to do this would be (if I want to iterate over every n-th element):

```
sample = "This is a string"
n = 3 # I want to iterate over every third element
i = 1
for x in sample:
    if i % n == 0:
        # do something with x
    else:
        # do something else with x
    i += 1
```

Is there any "pythonic" way to do this? (I am pretty sure my method is not good)

Comment: `for i,x in enumerate(sample,1):`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to do something every nth step, and something else for other cases, you could use `enumerate` to get the index, and use modulus:

```
sample = "This is a string"
n = 3 # I want to iterate over every third element
for i,x in enumerate(sample):
    if i % n == 0:
        print("do something with x "+x)
    else:
        print("do something else with x "+x)
```

Note that it doesn't start at 1 but 0. Add an offset to `i` if you want something else.

To iterate on every nth element only, the best way is to use `itertools.islice` to avoid creating a "hard" string just to iterate on it:

```
import itertools
for s in itertools.islice(sample,None,None,n):
    print(s)
```

result:

```
T
s
s

r
g
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer

Answer (score 20):

you can use `step` for example `sample[start:stop:step]`

If you want to iterate over every second element you can do :

```
sample = "This is a string"

for x in sample[::2]:
    print(x)
```

**output**

```
T
i

s
a
s
r
n
```

Comment: it doesn't answer to "do something every even item and do something else every odd item" though.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes but still it is useful and partly answers my question

Answer (score 1):

Logic to print every nth character:

```
#Sample input = 'abcdefghijkl'
#n = 4
for i in range(0,4):
    for x in input[i::4]:
        print(x, end='')
```

Output:

```
aeibfjcgkdhl
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `slice`:

```
sample = "This is a string"
for i in sample[slice(None,None,2)]:
   print(i)
```

Output:

```
T
i

s
a
s
r
n
```

Comment: `sample[slice(None,None,2)]` is the same as `sample[::2]`. Using `slice` in that context isn't really useful. It still creates a sub-list