# Is there a way to select a block of n elements from a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of n elements and I want to select 24 elements of that list at every cycle.
For example, I have exa that contains 1000 elements and I want to select 24 elements first, then the second 24 elements, then the third 24 elements and so on..

```
exa = [1, 2, 3, ...., 1000]
```

How I can put this into Python?

Comment: I think this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51121911/iterate-over-every-nth-element-in-string-in-loop-python

Comment: @GregorySky that's every n-th element, not n elements every n-th

Comment: Do you mean randomly select 24 elements from the list for X times?